# Python creating an array with elements from a matrix in a for loop

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing

I've been searching stack overflow for this answer.
I have a two column array:

```
A = np.column_stack((design[:,2],design[:,3]))
Alist = []
```

After this, I want to create an array of matrices in a for loop

```
for i in range(0,samples):
    AmatExtra = np.array[[1, A[i][0], A[i][1],0,0], [1, -A[i][0], A[i][1], 0,0], [1, 0, -A[i][1], 1,0],[1, 0, -A[i][1], 0,1],[0, 0, 0, 0,0],[0, 0, 0, 0,0]]
    Alist.append(AmatExtra)
```

However, when I try to do this I get "'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable" error.

Any tips on how to solve this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: please provide an example of the input and the matching expected output

Comment: Look at `np.array[[1...`  See the [?  The correct use is `np.array(...`, a function call, not indexing

Comment: Before spending a lot off time searching the web', spend time with the traceback, and search your own code.  And the documentation.